# Xamarin Forms: Remote Images don't load on Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I've been playing with Xamarin Forms, I create a simple app that consumes themoviedb api it shows the a movie list in a ListView control, pretty straightforward. I left it for some weeks, yesterday I gave it a try and I notice the images in Android Simulator never show up, the same with a physical device, the only variance I had was I created the project with VS2017 and now I open it with VS2019 (Community Edition both), googling I see some posts (very few though) that point out the problem was the https images and the HttpClient config, I checked and everything looked fine out-of-box [image]

I tested many other things such creating a brand new project with a simple image, try with a different image in the same app and no luck, I test the app in iOS and everything looks correct.\

[image]

The App only has 1 page, this is the XAML of it:
https://github.com/olman21/xamarin-movies/blob/master/Xamarin.Movies/Xamarin.Movies/Views/SearchMoviePage.xaml

Image XAML

```
<Image Source="{Binding BackdropPath, Converter={StaticResource movieDbImageConverter}}"
                               Aspect="AspectFill"
                               HeightRequest="160"
                               Grid.Row="0"/>
```

movieDbImageConverter

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var imageName = value as string;
        if (imageName == null) return string.Empty;

        return ImageSource.FromUri(new Uri($"{internalSettings.MovieDbImageBaseUrl}/{imageName}"));
    }
```

And this is the full Repo: https://github.com/olman21/xamarin-movies

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Did you look at xamarin log\logcat errors?

Comment: Is it only on Android? Can you please post the problematic XAML here? Did you update Xamarin nuget packages before trying?

Comment: do you have internet permissions enabled in the Android manifest?

Comment: @Oleg where can I look those logs?

Comment: @Prateek I haven't upgrade any package.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/deploy-test/debugging/android-debug-log?tabs=windows

Comment: @Jason yes I do, it's the only permission I have at this moment.

Comment: @Oleg no luck, those logs don't show anything relevant to this issue

Comment: Did you have network permissions in android project, check android manifest tab

Comment: @CSharper, well you should have latest

Comment: @Oleg my only permission is
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: Try to remove HasUnevenRows="True" from Listview and did you update project latest packages?

Comment: @Oleg yes I just upgraded everything to the latest version also remove HasUnevenRows prop and no luck.

Comment: @Prateek I edited the question with the problematic XAML

Comment: Try to debug MovieDbImageConverter.cs, out breakpoint  into Convert function.

Comment: @Oleg I did and everything seems correct, also I tried removing that converter and putting a static URL to image source but It is still no working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the issue, I figured it out.

Change `new Uri($"{internalSettings.MovieDbImageBaseUrl}/{imageName}");` to

```cs
new Uri($"{internalSettings.MovieDbImageBaseUrl}{imageName}");
```

ex URL is `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/nRXO2SnOA75OsWhNhXstHB8ZmI3.jpg` not `https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500//nRXO2SnOA75OsWhNhXstHB8ZmI3.jpg`

Browsers understand that Android OS wont apprently.

Comment: You are completely right, it's likely that The Movie Db API changed that adding the slash at the beginning of the name, and I completely misread it and assume that the URL was correct because the browser show me the picture, a embarrassing rookie error, thank you so much to take the time and leading me to the solution.

Comment: Additionally, I created a test project just with an Image with a static Source, It works well in the physical device but not in the simulator (that's why I discarded at the beginning the Custom Converter), It's kind of confusing how Android fails loading images.

`<Image x:Name="image" Source="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500/nRXO2SnOA75OsWhNhXstHB8ZmI3.jpg" />`